# circle the numbers in the tabular

Tags: tables, highlighting, circles

I have a question about the tabular. How do you obtain the attached tabular? [image]

Comment: The solutions presented in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/507652/134144 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40041/134144 should also work for your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for fun: a way to programmatically create this table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,column sep=0.2em,row sep=0.2em,
 nodes={execute at begin node={
 $\ifnum\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow<\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn
 {}\else\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\entry}{(10-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn)*
 (\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn-1)/2+\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow}
 \entry
 \fi$}}] (mat)
  { & & & & \\
    & & & & \\
    & & & & \\
    & & & & \\
    & & & & \\
  };
 \draw let \p1=($(mat-2-1)-(mat-3-2)$),\n1={90-atan2(\y1,\x1)} in 
  ($(mat-3-2)+(\n1-90:1.3ex)$) arc(\n1-90:\n1+90:1.3ex) -- 
  ($(mat-2-1)+(\n1+90:1.3ex)$) arc(\n1+90:\n1+270:1.3ex) -- cycle
 node[circle,draw,inner sep=1.3ex] at (mat-5-4){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]